# How to unveil a div with fixed contents

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I'm animating an element by unveiling it from the bottom of the page. The position of the child elements should not be affected by the size change of the unveiling animation.

That's what I'm looking for:

[image: goal]

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello stranger</h1>
</div>
```

Both elements are positioned `absolute` with top, right, bottom & left set to `0`.   The contents are revealed by lowering the `top` of the `div` from `100%` to `0%`. *Have a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/o8d79jum/10/).*

My goal is

1. to keep the heading always at a fixed position (middle)
2. hide the heading when it is not uncovered yet

But these are my problems  *<sub><sup>(Fiddles included)</sup></sub>*

- When using `position:fixed` for the `h1` the `overflow` [becomes always visible](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/o8d79jum/10/).
- When using `position:absolute` the position [isn't `fixed` correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/o8d79jum/3/).
- When using `clip:rect(500px auto auto auto)` I lose the ability to use `%`. And thus I can't determine the exact height of the viewport without using JavaScript.

**What else can be done to archieve the described behavour without JS?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to move the `h1` in the opposite direction to the `div` animation at the same time which gives the illusion that the `h1` has remained static. However the `h1` is actually also moving relative to the `div` just in the opposite direction.

I've kept the same markup and also the `position: absolute; top: 0; right:0; left:0; bottom: 0;` requirement you stated on both elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/eLbcdc9c/6/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello stranger</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #000;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate3d(0, 50%, 0);
}

/* Transition effect and timing must be the same for both elements to give the perfect illusion */
div,
h1 {
    transition: transform 500ms ease-in;
}

/* The transform class added to the div to begin the animation on the h1 and div at the same time */
.hide {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
.hide h1 {
    transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
}
```

Apply the `hide` class  to the `div` (by clicking the toggle in the fiddle) and you should get the desired affect.

Things that are important to note here is the use of 3dtransforms. These are much smoother than animating `top` or `margins` and takes advantage of using a devices [GPU for Hardware acceleration](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_movement_smoothly_using_css.htm) to achieve this.

3dtransforms are [very well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=3dtransforms) but you may need to apply the browser prefixes in some instances depending on the support you want to offer.

Comment: Great answer!  Especially the part about the GPU acceleration. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you could just change the h1 from `position:absolute` to `fixed`.

**http://jsfiddle.net/o8d79jum/8/**

```css
div {
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:100%;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    animation:ani 2s infinite;
}
h1 {
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    margin:0;
}
@keyframes ani {
    0% {
        top:100%;
    }
    100% {
        top:0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
     <h1>Hi, I'm centerized</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; Unfortunately I can't use `position:fixed` because it renderes the heading as always visible (see [your fiddle (edited)](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/o8d79jum/9/)). Any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: @RienNeVaPlu͢s well, can't you set it to the same color as the default background like the demo?

Comment: The project I'm working on, uses images additional to the heading, so I can't fake it's visibility (`opacity` wont do the job either). I stripped the code in the question for the sake of simplicty.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes my attempt, using a pseudo element to hide the h1

This pseudo element has an arbitrary high height, and is positioned always at the upper side of the div.

```
div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 9999px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8d79jum/11/)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative  you could translate the `div:after` on top of your text :

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/o8d79jum/15/)**

```js
$$('button').first().on('click', function(e){ $$('body').first().toggleClassName('animate'); });
```

```css
body{
    margin:0
}


div {
     position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow:hidden
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    top:0;
    z-index:999;
}
h1 {
    position:absolute;
    color:red;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.animate div:after {
    animation-name:ani;
    animation-duration:2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes ani {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    
    100% {
       transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
}
button{position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;
z-index:9999}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2/prototype.min.js"></script>
<div><h1>Hi, I'm centerized</h1></div>


<button>Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want [exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/o8d79jum/5/).

You need to do this. And see the css in the exemple.

```
<h1>Hello stranger</h1>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: I need to have the heading inside of the div. Just covering it up won't do the job for me :/

Comment: But your div height dosen't stay 100%. You want to center that heading at middle but your div hav just 20% height? I don't think you can to this. You need to have another div to align the text or something.

Comment: It [seems possible](http://jsfiddle.net/o8d79jum/7/) using `clip`. Just not with percentage units, which makes it hard to determine the height. So I thought there might be another way...

Comment: clip dosen't support percent height http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-clip but you could find something with javascript to determine the height